# Execute action on AsyncTask finish

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

**SITUATION**

I am developing and android app for my university math class (I'm using Android Studio). What I am doing in a particular fragment is the following:

1. Click the button "GENERATE"
2. Start the AsyncTask (there is a "big" for loop inside, it goes from 0 to 5000)
3. While the AsyncTask is running show a message like "Loading..."
4. When the AsyncTask has finished the calculations inside that foor loop, add TableRows to a TableLayout

As you can see here, I must execute that `for` loop in a "separate" place (the AsyncTask) because it is going to be a problem for the UI.

---

**PROBLEM**

I have troubles when I have to code the point number 4 of the above list. You can see the entire code in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FsJGHvj0). Here I want to point out the main problem.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_disequazioni_generali, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(), "", "Attendi...", false, true);

                //valori degli estremi
                EditText val_a = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.val_a);
                EditText val_b = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.val_b);
                a = Double.parseDouble(val_a.getText().toString());
                b = Double.parseDouble(val_b.getText().toString());
                derivata = getDerivative(funzione, variabili, "x");

                //setup tableview + task
                tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutTangenti);
                TextView coefficente = new TextView(view.getContext());
                EditText decimale = new EditText(view.getContext());

                mAuthTask = new TaskAsincrono();
                mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);

            }

        });
```

As you can see here I am creating a new object because I need to use the AsyncTask (look below):

```
public class TaskAsincrono  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void[] values) {

        };

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

                double x = a;
                double y = b;

                //Definizione dell'intervallo
                risultati = separaRadici(funzione, x, y, 500);

                int k = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < (risultati.size()); i += 2) {

                    k++;
                    double a = risultati.get(i);
                    double b = risultati.get(i + 1);
                    double res = (b + a) / 2;

                    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                        res = res - (getFunctionVal(funzione, res) / getFunctionVal(derivata, res));
                    }

                    soluzioni.add(res);

                }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if(dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss(); }

            //THE ISSUE IS HERE
            mostraRisultati();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
        }
    }
```

When the AsyncTask finished to work ( = it has completed all the operations inside the doInBackground) I need to call `mostraRisultati();`.

When the AsyncTask finished to execute the for loop, the dialog disappears but the method `mostraRisultati()` is not working. Any idea?

**Note:** If you look at the pastebin you can see the entire code. While testing, I have discovered that mostraRisultati() is called when the AsyncTask has finished its process, but the `for` loop is not running because `risultati.size()` is zero. What am I missing?

Comment: Your pastebin code has compilation errors. It's not the complete code.

Comment: Updated. I removed some useless parts but now I put the entire one. It looks like I have problems with the views

Comment: The `mostraRisultati` function or method exists nowhere in the code you've provided.  Where is it?

Comment: @user3137702 Its in his pastebin link

Comment: @user3137702 if you read carefully, you can see where it is

Comment: @DK64 Is your issue solved? I tried following and the trig functions there scared me away :(. I reckon the problem is with data that the methods are receiving. Did you try it with breakpoints to check whats missing?